# How to control publish rate in ROS-enabled plugins?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Are there any standard option for this? It used to be `<updateRate>` parameter, but it seems not to work anymore. Although there is `<update_rate>`, it works only for sensor plugins.

At the moment my model plugin publishes data in `OnUpdate()` function without any additional time control.

Should I publish the data in parallel thread and achieve necessary rate with something like `ros::Rate::sleep()` or there is a better option?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2058/how-to-control-publish-rate-in-ros-enabled-plugins?/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I don't think there is a dedicated function for this, but you can easily use it like this:

```
// set the update rate (you can also set it as a parameter from the sdf file)
this->updateRate = common::Time(0, common::Time::SecToNano(0.75));

// initialize the prevUpdateTime
this->prevUpdateTime = common::Time::GetWallTime();

void PluginClass::OnUpdate()
{
  if (common::Time::GetWallTime() - this->prevUpdateTime < this->updateRate)
    return;

  ...

  this->prevUpdateTime = common::Time::GetWallTime();
}
```

========UPDATE, HOW TO GET THE PARAMETER EXAMPLE=========

in the sdf file:

```
<plugin name='plugin_name' filename='libplugin_name.so'>
    <sdf_parameter_update_rate>69.0</sdf_parameter_update_rate>
</plugin>
```

in the plugin:

```
void PluginName::Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
...
double param_update_rate;

if (!_sdf->HasElement("sdf_parameter_update_rate"))
{
    // if parameter tag does NOT exist
    std::cout << "Missing parameter <sdf_parameter_update_rate> in PluginName, default to 0" << std::endl;
    param_update_rate = 0;
}
    // if parameter tag exists, get its value
else param_update_rate = _sdf->GetElement("sdf_parameter_update_rate")->GetValueDouble();
```

and then you use this `param_update_rate` in setting the updateRate value:

```
this->updateRate = common::Time(0, common::Time::SecToNano(param_update_rate));
```

Cheers, Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-03-25**:
Thanks, will give it a try. Does this->updateRate load from  or <update_rate> parameter?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-26**:
you set it in the code yourself ( common::Time(0, common::Time::SecToNano(0.75)); ), or you can load it as a parameter from the sdf file, I will update the answer to see how that is done

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-03-26**:
Yeah, I know how to get parameters from SDF, but thanks for the code snippets anyway! I was wondering if some of the legacy parameters that use to load automagically are still persist... Looks like not.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-04-11**:
Finally added this functionality to my plugin. The only concern is the `SecToNano()` function, see details [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2334/confusion-with-commontimesectonano/).